# Управление "не существует" - именительный или родительный падеж?

Tags: падежи, отрицание

Какое из предложенний построенно корректно? Почему?

"Лампа не существует" И.П.

"Лампы не существует" Р.П.

Answer (score 6):

В [статье](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=2bfJAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA301&lpg=PA301&dq=%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%81+%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC+%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6&source=bl&ots=kQHzASgJy_&sig=9NecI5U3-u9G2n3m6M-SxpUlhsA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_qLi7qOLcAhViApoKHeE_B30Q6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6&f=false) Менгель С. "К вопросу о падежной вариативности в русских конструкциях с отрицанием" в сборнике "Горизонты современной лингвистики. Традиции и новаторство: сборник в честь Е. С. Кубряковой" сказано:

> Единственным из экзистенциальных глаголов, допускающим как
>   именительный, так и родительный падеж при отрицании, является глагол
>   *существовать*

Но на мой взгляд формы именительного и родительного падежей не полностью взаимозаменяемы, так как отличаются семантическим оттенком.

Таким образом корректны оба варианта.

Comment: c "не бывает" тоже можно

Comment: @shabunc не уверен, сравним: "у нас снега не бывает" И "у нас снег не бывает", второе предложение скорее означает, что снег к нам не заходит (такова первая мысль о его значении)...  в то же время из двух фраз "он здесь не бывает" И "его здесь не бывает", в которых речь идёт об одушевлённом существе, более идиоматичной на мой взгляд является первая, скорей всего с глаголом "быть" в отрицательных конструкциях к И.п. тяготеют одушевлённые предметы, а к Р.п. неодушевлённые

Comment: да, пожалуй вы правы. Интересно, никогда не задумывался

Comment: There are more verbs like that if you allow adverbials: *здесь лоси не водятся / здесь лосей не водится, здесь трава не растёт / здесь травы не растёт* etc., however it seems like it's the only verb which allows both cases in a bare sentence indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю, падеж здесь зависит от грамматической роли существительного:

- *лампа не существует* — лампа является главным действующим лицом (вот лампа, и её не существует);
- *лампы не существует* — подлежащее опущено, а потому лампа является неким объектом, попавшим под влияние внешних обстоятельств, чьё состояние мы просто констатируем.

То есть первый вариант более прямолинейный и предметный.